# Google Nexus 7 didn't recognize via USB

Tags: android, adb, nexus-7

Please help me. I'm trying to connect my Google Nexus 7 to my PC for Android development.

I've tried connecting to my PC with different cables. When I connected the device to my Windows 7 PC, I didn't get any notification on Android or my PC that device was connected. In "Other devices"  my PC shows `Unknown device`. I try use **MTP** and **PTP**, as well as disabling and enabling USB debugging. I've used **Nexus Root Toolkit**, **Universal Naked Driver**, **Nexus 7 toolkit**, and I've tried this tutorial and many other **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjWjCQXlWDc** and nothing has helped me.

I don't understand why there aren't any notifications on Android. Could it be a hardware problem? How i can check it?

Please help me, because I haven't found any way to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install the ADB driver for the Nexus 7.  Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731871/adb-driver-for-htc-incredible) resolution.

Here is a link to all [Android ADB drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure you have the 'USB Debugging' setting enabled on the Nexus7.   You can download the USB driver using the SDK Manager (the same way you downloaded different SDKs and tools).